# In an interview should I mention that I left a job due to illness?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

This was 1 year ago, and I've been working freelance since.

I've got an interview coming up for a full time role and was wondering what to say if they brought up why I left the job.

Lie or tell the truth?

Comment: you can elaborate more your question

Answer (score 1):

If/when they ask you, it's not a bad reason, assuming you can convince them that you aren't going to suffer a relapse any time soon. Not sure it's worth going out f your way to make that point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Honesty is the best policy.

If you illness was physical I don't see how this could be taken against you, especially that you have worked since.

If this was of a mental issue (e.g. depression) then you should be prepared to explain the steps you undertook to resolve the issue. 
(As pointed out in a comment this applies to a physical issues too)

Also remember the fact you lied about your medical issue may surface after you get a job - if you require time for checkups, rehabilitation, the illness comes back etc - if you ask for flexibility around this and it becomes clear that it's an old problem that you lied about you may face serious consequences.

Having said that, the amount of detail and how open you are about your illness will depend on the culture you are part of.

Comment: Shouldn't both mental and physical illness be treated the same. Most of us will experience some mental illness some time in our lives

Comment: @EdHeal I'm not arguing they should or shouldn't. I only wanted to point out that if you talk about mental illness you have be prepared to deal with stigma.

Comment: You said _then you should be prepared to explain the steps you undertook to resolve the issue._ - This should apply to physical illness as well